# Vim in shell allows <alt>[a-z] to circumvent having to press <escape> to get out of INSERT mode. How can I apply this to Gui implimentations of Vim?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, vim, gvim, vi

Vim in shell allows `<alt>[a-z]` to circumvent having to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get out of INSERT mode. For example,

Open up a terminal and set its editing mode away from emacs, to vi

```
set -o vi
```

Now enter INSERT mode and start typing:

```
<i>[Type some words]
```

Before you press enter, hold alt, and press "u" for undo:

```
<left alt><u>
```

This will take you out of INSERT mode, and will undo your last change.

---

If I try to do this in GVIM, `<left alt><u>` will type "õ". I would rather have it the other way.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Once in gvim, you can type `:help quickref` and hit  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

That'll bring you to the hotkeys information of gvim.
I'm pretty sure you'll find everything you need there, worth to take a look. Good luck buddy! :-)

Comment: Could you be more specific as to how to solve the problem specified in the op?